# Take screenshot on test failure in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot

I am trying to write a selenium code which takes screenshot on test failure.

This is written inside Listeners class.

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("***** Error " + result.getName() + " test has failed *****");
    ITestContext context = result.getTestContext();
    WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) context.getAttribute("driver");
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File src = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
    System.out.println(src.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        FileHandler.copy(src, new File("./Screenshots/OnboardingTestFailed.png"));
        System.out.println("Screenshot taken");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem I am facing is with line 
File src = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

This statement is throwing NullPointerException.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure WedDriver has been initialized properly? Seems it is null, hence the exception.

Comment: Correct, WebDriver was not initialized properly. Can you guide how to pass the driver object from my test which is in another class to this Listeners class

Comment: @AAINAARORA, hi. Provide response below with a code snippet included. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to do the following trick here:

1) firstly, create Screen interface.

```
package com.ej.alumni.selenium.testcases.core;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public interface Screen {

    WebDriver getDriver();
}
```

2)  Test suite class will be represented in the following way:

```
public class LoginTest implements Screen {
    private WebDriver driver;
    @Test(groups = {"LOGIN"})
    public void myPrimaryTest() 

        //driver init
        driver = .... ; 
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        // ....
    }

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

3) And to get **WebDriver** instance in listener-  should be implemented:

```
public class CustomTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        try {
            Object currentClass = result.getInstance();
            if (currentClass instanceof Screen) {
                WebDriver driver = ((Screen) currentClass).getDriver();
                byte[] srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                saveScreenshot(srcFile);
                postBrowserLogs(driver);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Error e1 = new Error(e.getMessage());
            e1.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());
            throw e1;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {

        Object currentClass = result.getInstance();
        if (currentClass instanceof Screen) {
            WebDriver driver = ((Screen) currentClass).getDriver();
            byte[] srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            saveScreenshot(srcFile);
            postBrowserLogs(driver);
        }

    }


    @Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type = "image/png")
    private byte[] saveScreenshot(byte[] screenshot) {
        return screenshot;
    }
}
```

Hope this works for You.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any listener if it's complicated for you. Simply follow the below workaround.

1: User @AfterMethod annotation 
2: Pass ITestResult as the parameter and driver (if take screenshot method is in a different class)
3: In after test call the take screenshot method. On the basis of ITestResult, capture the screen.

```
@AfterMethod
public void after_method(ITestResult result, WebDriver driver) {
    takeScreenshot(result,driver);
}

public void takeScreenshot(ITestResult result,WebDriver driver) {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        byte[] srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    // add more code to save file
}
```

}